# Confirm meaning of 水を張った大きな箱

Tags: translation

The phrase in question comes from がばいばあちゃん p.167, ch. 13.

I think 水を張った大きな箱 means a box filled with water (and tofu, as it says elsewhere in the text).

I'm a little confused because I thought 張る is used with 氷 to say 'spreading ice' or 'forming ice'.

Please clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

張る has [27 meanings in this dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/180264/meaning/m0u/).

What you already know is this,

> **５** 一面におおう。「池に氷が―・る」

while the one you see is this:

> **６** いっぱいにする。「浴槽に水を―・る」

This usage typically co-occurs with "water", but applicable to any (clear) liquid.

Comment: I see! Maybe I should use Japanese-to-Japanese dictionaries more often. Effectively, 6 is equivalent to fill (e.g. with water). Thanks for that!

Comment: @Robert 張る roughly means "to spread" or "to get tense", but basically you may have to individually memorize which nouns go well with 張る. Some verbs such as する, かける and とる can be really tricky for learners (they are [light verbs](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/42909/8629)).